# Trouble returning bool from recursive function

Tags: python, recursion, graph-theory

I'm working on a homework problem in which we have to write an algorithm that can determine if a graph is bipartite or not.  My python solution works, but right now it throws an exception if the graph is not bipartite, instead I would like it to return a bool.  How could I modify this code?

```
def is_bipartite(v, visited, colors, counter):

    print(v)

    # Set this vertex to visited
    visited[v] = True
    colors[v] = counter % 2

    # Explore links
    for u in v.links:

        # If linked up node u has already been visited, check its color to see if it breaks
        # the bipartite of the graph
        if u in visited:

            if colors[v] == colors[u]:

                raise Exception("Not Bipartite")

        # If the link has not be visited then visit it
        if u not in visited:

            visited[u] = False

            is_bipartite(u, visited, colors, counter + 1)
```

Comment: is there a reason you can't just `return True` for the exception and then `return is_bipartite(...)` at the recursion call? If you can do that just add a `return False` at the end and you're good

Comment: That doesn't seem to work.  I changed the Exception to return False, and added return True at the end of the function and It always returns true, even in cases where the Exception would have been triggered.

Comment: Are you also returning the return of `is_bipartite`? You need three `returns` in your function for it to function recursively.

Comment: Yes, If my last line is return True, I always get true.  If I omit the final line I just get 'None', even when it should be False.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your code correctly, you want to return `False` if you get matching colors anywhere along your recursive search. You want to return `True` if you get to the end of the search without finding anything.

That is not too hard to do. Just change the `raise` statement to `return False` and check the result of the recursive calls, and return `False` if any of them return a `False` result. Then just put `return True` at the end of the function and you're done:

```
def is_bipartite(v, visited, colors, counter):
    visited[v] = True
    colors[v] = counter % 2
    for u in v.links:
        if u in visited:
            if colors[v] == colors[u]:
                return False                # return instead of raise in this base case

        if u not in visited:
            visited[u] = False
            if not is_bipartite(u, visited, colors, counter + 1): # check the recursion
                return False                                      # pass on any False

    return True  # return True only if you got to the end without returning False above
```

Comment: Yes this appears to work with my test cases.  I failed to check the result of the recursive call, rather I was just trying to return it directly.